# Unable to download files via powershell from Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, file-download

I used to be able to download files from Sharepoint Online by logging in with `Connect-PnPOnline` and then running the following command; but today it put a real kink in my productivity and it didn't download:

```
PS C:\Users\ajleer> Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/PointofSale/Shared Documents/General/Forms `(Food`)/Menu Items + Online.xlsm" -AsFile -Path "C:\Users\ajleer\OneDrive - SomeCompany\Projects\Simph-Menu-Item-Find-York\src\xlsx" -Filename "Grantville Menu Item Request x.xlsm" -Force
Get-PnPFile : One or more errors occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/PointofSale/Shared Documents/General/For ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPFile], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.GetFile
```

I also checked my modules with the following, looks like I have some old versions in there:

```
PS C:\Users\ajleer> Get-Module -ListAvailable | ? { $_.Name -like "*Pn*" }


    Directory: C:\Users\ajleer\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
PSImplicitRemotingMessage, Modify-PSImplicitRemotingParameters, Get-PSImplicitRemotingSessionOption...}
Manifest   1.10.0     PnP.PowerShell                      {Add-PnPAdaptiveScopeProperty, Add-PnPPropertyBagValue, Copy-PnPFolder, Export-PnPClientSidePage...}
Manifest   1.9.0      PnP.PowerShell                      {Add-PnPClientSidePageSection, Add-PnPClientSideText, Add-PnPClientSideWebPart, Copy-PnPFolder...}
Manifest   1.8.0      PnP.PowerShell                      {Add-PnPClientSidePage, Add-PnPClientSidePageSection, Add-PnPClientSideText, Add-PnPClientSideWebPart...}
Manifest   1.7.0      PnP.PowerShell                      {Add-PnPClientSidePage, Add-PnPClientSidePageSection, Add-PnPClientSideText, Add-PnPClientSideWebPart...}
Manifest   1.6.0      PnP.PowerShell                      {Add-PnPClientSidePage, Add-PnPClientSidePageSection, Add-PnPClientSideText, Add-PnPClientSideWebPart...}
Manifest   1.5.0      PnP.PowerShell                      {Add-PnPClientSidePage, Add-PnPClientSidePageSection, Add-PnPClientSideText, Add-PnPClientSideWebPart...}


        Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
    
    
    ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
    ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
    Manifest   1.0.0.0    PnpDevice                           {Get-PnpDevice, Get-PnpDeviceProperty, Enable-PnpDevice, Disable-PnpDevice}
    Manifest   2.0.0.0    VpnClient                           {Add-VpnConnection, Set-VpnConnection, Remove-VpnConnection, Get-VpnConnection...}
```

I also added this to a bug listed [here](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/1751).

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are using using? Try with latest PowerShell.

Comment: @RajatSahani 5.1.19041.610

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are same issue with PowerShell 5.1.

It will work great with PowerShell 7.2.1.

Refer the below thread

- [Get-PnPFile fails to download multiple small files in a row](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/1618)